# Overlap issue in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout where some text of `id="txt-bar"` will overlap with `id="image"` and `id="main-content-area"` will also overlap to `id="image"` content. But in the following layout some space appears in between `id="main-content-area"` and `id="footer"`.I don't know how to solve this. I am new to html and css, please help me.

```css
body{
  position:absolute;
}
#top-bar{
  background-color:black;

  color:white;
}

#txt-bar{
  height:40px;
  background-color:pink;
  position:relative;
  z-index:4;
}


#link-bar{

  background-color:red;
  height:40px;
  z-index:4;
}


#image{
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}

.line{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

#main-content-area{
  position:relative;
  background-color:red;
  top:-60px;
  z-index:4;
}
#footer{
  background-color:green;

  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="top-bar">
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h4> Some links </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="txt-bar">
      <h1>Greetings</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="link-bar"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="image">
      <img src="me.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="main-content-area">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:green">
        <h3>Welcome </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="download.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="download.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="download.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="footer">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>some text........</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>some link </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're actually trying to achieve here.  The gap exists because of the `top:-60px;` rule but it's all a bit of a jumbled mess.  Can you reduce the amount of code to something a bit more concise?

Comment: @Nhan: there is a blank space appears in between id="main-conten-area" and id="footer", that is my problem

Comment: @ billynoah : is there any other way to achieve the result without using top:-60px ? but gap should not be there and id="main-content-area" should overlap to id="image"

Comment: yes but it's really hard to understand what "result" you're trying for here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `z-index` the position of that element must be either `absolute` or `fixed` or `relative`. At least one of your elements up there has a `z-index` with a `static` position (the default).

Comment: evilgenious448: Check this, we can use z-index with relative  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: this is wrong, z-index works fine for `position: relative`